# How to make zxing open a URL in a browser or dial a number after scanning

Tags: android, android-intent, zxing

[What I want the app to do after scanning is to dial the number instead of displaying it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Sdkk.png)So I'm new to Android developing and zxing library. I've been able to create a standalone QR scanner app using the zxing library but the issue is that when it scans the QR code, I want it to either open the URL in a browser or do something else based on the content of the QR instead of displaying the string content of the QR code. Example, if the string content of the QR code is a URL "www.stackoverflow.com", I want the app to take me to the site instead of displaying the string content of the QR code.

This is the code for my CaptureActivity

```
package com.skyers.jwetherell.quick_response_code;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.skyers.google.zxing.Result;
import com.skyers.google.zxing.ResultMetadataType;
import com.skyers.jwetherell.quick_response_code.result.ResultHandler;
import com.skyers.jwetherell.quick_response_code.result.ResultHandlerFactory;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class CaptureActivity extends com.skyers.jwetherell.quick_response_code.DecoderActivity {

    private static final String TAG = CaptureActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final Set<ResultMetadataType> DISPLAYABLE_METADATA_TYPES = EnumSet.of(ResultMetadataType.ISSUE_NUMBER, ResultMetadataType.SUGGESTED_PRICE,
        ResultMetadataType.ERROR_CORRECTION_LEVEL, ResultMetadataType.POSSIBLE_COUNTRY);

    private TextView statusView = null;
    private View resultView = null;
    private boolean inScanMode = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.capture);
        Log.v(TAG, "onCreate()");

        resultView = findViewById(R.id.result_view);
        statusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_view);

        inScanMode = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.v(TAG, "onDestroy()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.v(TAG, "onResume()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.v(TAG, "onPause()");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if (inScanMode)
                finish();
            else
                onResume();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleDecode(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode) {
        drawResultPoints(barcode, rawResult);

        ResultHandler resultHandler = ResultHandlerFactory.makeResultHandler(this, rawResult);
        handleDecodeInternally(rawResult, resultHandler, barcode);
    }

    protected void showScanner() {
        inScanMode = true;
        resultView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        statusView.setText(R.string.msg_default_status);
        statusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewfinderView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    protected void showResults() {
        inScanMode = false;
        statusView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewfinderView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        resultView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    // Put up our own UI for how to handle the decodBarcodeFormated contents.
    private void handleDecodeInternally(Result rawResult, ResultHandler resultHandler, Bitmap barcode) {
        onPause();
        showResults();

        ImageView barcodeImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.barcode_image_view);
        if (barcode == null) {
            barcodeImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.skyers));
        } else {
            barcodeImageView.setImageBitmap(barcode);
        }

        TextView formatTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.format_text_view);
        formatTextView.setText(rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());

        TextView typeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.type_text_view);
        typeTextView.setText(resultHandler.getType().toString());

        DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT);
        String formattedTime = formatter.format(new Date(rawResult.getTimestamp()));
        TextView timeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_text_view);
        timeTextView.setText(formattedTime);

        TextView metaTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.meta_text_view);
        View metaTextViewLabel = findViewById(R.id.meta_text_view_label);
        metaTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        metaTextViewLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Map<ResultMetadataType, Object> metadata = rawResult.getResultMetadata();
        if (metadata != null) {
            StringBuilder metadataText = new StringBuilder(20);
            for (Map.Entry<ResultMetadataType, Object> entry : metadata.entrySet()) {
                if (DISPLAYABLE_METADATA_TYPES.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                    metadataText.append(entry.getValue()).append('\n');
                }
            }
            if (metadataText.length() > 0) {
                metadataText.setLength(metadataText.length() - 1);
                metaTextView.setText(metadataText);
                metaTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                metaTextViewLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        TextView contentsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contents_text_view);
        CharSequence displayContents = resultHandler.getDisplayContents();
        contentsTextView.setText(displayContents);
        // Crudely scale betweeen 22 and 32 -- bigger font for shorter text
        int scaledSize = Math.max(22, 32 - displayContents.length() / 4);
        contentsTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, scaledSize);
    }
}
```

And this is the code for my ResultHandler

```
package com.skyers.jwetherell.quick_response_code.result;

import android.app.Activity;

import com.skyers.google.zxing.Result;
import com.skyers.google.zxing.client.result.ParsedResult;
import com.skyers.google.zxing.client.result.ParsedResultType;

public abstract class ResultHandler {

    private final ParsedResult result;
    private final Activity activity;
    private final Result rawResult;

    ResultHandler(Activity activity, ParsedResult result) {
        this(activity, result, null);
    }

    ResultHandler(Activity activity, ParsedResult result, Result rawResult) {
        this.result = result;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.rawResult = rawResult;
    }

    public ParsedResult getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    Activity getActivity() {
        return activity;
    }

    public Result getRawResult() {
        return rawResult;
    }

    public boolean areContentsSecure() {
        return false;
    }

    public CharSequence getDisplayContents() {
        String contents = result.getDisplayResult();
        return contents.replace("\r", "");
    }

    public abstract int getDisplayTitle();

    public final ParsedResultType getType() {
        return result.getType();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You question is not very clear, you have to put some source code to explain your issue.

You could use this library: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent

and in your activity:

```
private void launchScanBarcode(){
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(yourActivity);
    integrator.initiateScan();
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
  IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
  if (scanResult != null) {
    // handle scan result with scanResult.getContents() or scanResult.getRawBytes()
  }
  // else continue with any other code you need in the method
  ...
}
```

Comment: can you please explain better since I'm new to android programming. Where do I put the codes you posted?

Comment: I have been able to sort myself out...I realized I'd left out some files from the zxing library. Thanks for your help though @LaurentY